# firefox language de-ch (german part of switzerland) not available

Tags: javascript, firefox, number-formatting

first of all. i'm aware that i can format numbers using js.
i would like to avoid to maintain an retrieve a setting from the server which specifies the format

my numbers in question are js floats and should be displayed in the format of the language the user selects in the browser.

i would like to rely on (modern) browser settings to format my decimal numbers
in switzerland we use the decimal point "."
so my script gets the navigator.languages[0] value to use it with the `intl.date` and `intl.number` - objects (those work fine when feeding in "de-ch" as culture)
but it turns out on firefox i can only select "de" (Deutsch) as language in the options. This gets used then for the formatting and uses the "," for decimal point.
why isn't there a "de-ch" (Deutsch-Schweiz) setting in the firefox language options?

my current workaround (and to give a bit more context to this questions) is:

```
let mostPreferedLanguage = globalThis.navigator.languages[0]
if (
  mostPreferedLanguage === "de" &&
  navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") > -1
) {
  if ((1.1).toString().indexOf(".") > -1) {
    mostPreferedLanguage = "de-ch"
  }
}
export let displayFormats = {
  decimal: {
    default: new Intl.NumberFormat(mostPreferedLanguage, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2
    }),
    _4Digits: new Intl.NumberFormat(mostPreferedLanguage, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 4,
      maximumFractionDigits: 4
    })
  },
  date: {
    default: new Intl.DateTimeFormat(mostPreferedLanguage, {
      day: "2-digit",
      month: "2-digit",
      year: "numeric"
    }),
    _2DigitsYear: new Intl.DateTimeFormat(mostPreferedLanguage, {
      day: "2-digit",
      month: "2-digit",
      year: "2-digit"
    }),
    defaultTimestamp: new Intl.DateTimeFormat(mostPreferedLanguage, {
      day: "2-digit",
      month: "2-digit",
      year: "2-digit",
      hour: "numeric",
      minute: "numeric",
      second: "numeric",
      hour12: false
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: just added a workaround. there  you can see that in case of firefox i just do a .toString() of a float which somehow (maybe using windows settings) is using the correct format...